# How to prove $\tan x+\tan \left(x+\frac{\pi }{3}\right)+\tan \left(x+\frac{2\pi }{3}\right)=3\tan 3x$?

Tags: trigonometry

The following is the equation.

\begin{eqnarray}
\tan x+\tan \left(x+\frac{\pi }{3}\right)+\tan \left(x+\frac{2\pi }{3}\right)&=&3\tan 3x\\
\tan x+\frac{\tan x+\tan \frac{\pi }{3}}{1-\tan x\space \tan \frac{\pi }{3}}+\frac{\tan x+\tan \frac{2\pi }{3}}{1-\tan x\space \tan \frac{2\pi }{3}} &=& 3\tan 3x\\
\end{eqnarray}

I think that : 
\begin{eqnarray}
\tan \frac{2\pi }{3}=-\tan \frac{\pi }{3}\\
\end{eqnarray}

Therefore,

\begin{eqnarray} \tan x+\frac{\tan x+\tan \frac{\pi }{3}}{1-\tan x\space \tan \frac{\pi }{3}}+\frac{\tan x-\tan \frac{\pi }{3}}{1+\tan x\space \tan \frac{\pi }{3}}&=&3\tan 3x\\ \end{eqnarray}

For me, it's too complex to continue...
Maybe there are something wrong. 
Are there any other methods to prove the answer easily?

**Thank you for your attention.**

Comment: You get more symmetry if you consider it as a function of $y = x + \frac{\pi}{3}$. Maybe that helps?

Comment: Are you restricting the identity to the interval $-\frac \pi 6 < x < \frac \pi 6$?

Comment: There is no restricted interval stated on the paper. I just need to prove the ans...I think trigonometry is so difficult.

Comment: You should remove "$=3\tan 3x$" from your equations until you have shown that your expression does indeed equal $3\tan 3x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$\tan3x=\tan3A$$

$\implies 3x=n\pi+3A,x =\frac{n\pi}3+A$ where $n$ is any integer

We can set $x=A,\frac\pi3+A,\frac{2\pi}3+A$ (In fact, we can any three in-congruent values of $n\pmod 3$)

Now,

$$\tan3A=\tan3x=\frac{3\tan x-\tan^3x}{1-3\tan^2x}$$

On rearrangement, $$\tan^3x-3\tan3A\tan^2x-3\tan x+\tan3A=0$$ which is a cubic equation in $\tan x$

Now, apply Vieta's formula to find

$\sum \tan x=3\tan3A,\prod\tan x=-\tan3A $